# Amazon SimpleDB for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, amazon-simpledb

Does anyone know a good library or sample code to add new entry to a domain using REST?

Comment: I found the answer here. http://notebookheavy.com/2011/11/15/amazon-simpledb-basics-in-c-putattribute/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon Web Services SDK for Windows Phone has recently been released. This SDK provides developers with a speed dial that lets you quickly connect and integrate Windows Phone applications with AWS S3, SimpleDB and SQS services.

The SDK can be found from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft-Interop/AWS-SDK-for-WP).

---

**These articles are not about SDK. They're about manually connectting to SimpleDB from Windows Phone; and written before the SDK.**

Here is series of articles written in Turkish:

Original: http://muhammedbaykal.com/post/Windows-Phone-75-Amazon-AWS-SimpleDb-Part-I.aspx
Google Translated: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=tr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=tr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmuhammedbaykal.com%2Fpost%2FWindows-Phone-75-Amazon-AWS-SimpleDb-Part-I.aspx&act=url

Part II: http://muhammedbaykal.com/post/Windows-Phone-75-Amazon-AWS-SimpleDb-Part-II.aspx
Google Translated: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=tr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=tr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmuhammedbaykal.com%2Fpost%2FWindows-Phone-75-Amazon-AWS-SimpleDb-Part-II.aspx&act=url

Part III: http://muhammedbaykal.com/post/Windows-Phone-75-Amazon-AWS-SimpleDb-Part-III.aspx
Google Translated: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=tr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=tr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmuhammedbaykal.com%2Fpost%2FWindows-Phone-75-Amazon-AWS-SimpleDb-Part-III.aspx&act=url

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has a full [.NET SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/).

---

**Edit**

I stand corrected! I wasn't aware Windows Phone was lacking full .NET support. 
There is however a blog series [here](http://notebookheavy.com/2011/10/10/amazon-simpledb-for-windows-phone-part-1-signature/) discussing accessing SimpleDb from Windows Phone 7. It covers the signature, which is probably the trickiest part to get right on your own!

Its also probably worth looking at the official .NET SDK in reflector to see what is happening.

Comment: This SDK is not WP7 supported!